# Add Arraylist data to database

Tags: c#, database, variables, arraylist

I have some variables which are Arraylists and some are strings. I have class method which takes variables from another class using inheritence and add them to database.Here is my code:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Darius\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FilmuBiblioteka\FilmuBiblioteka\duombaze.mdf");

            sqlConnection1.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT filmai (Id, Pavadinimas, Metai, trukme, salis, kalba, reitingas, zanras, aktoriai, link, plot, rezisieriai) VALUES (@Id, @Title, @Year, @Runtime, @Countries, @Languages, @Rating, @Genres, @Cast, @ImdbURL, @Plot, @Directors)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", Title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", Year);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Runtime", Runtime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Countries", Countries); *
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Languages", Languages); *
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rating", Rating);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Genres", Genres); *
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cast", Cast); *
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ImdbURL", ImdbURL);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Plot", Plot);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Directors", Directors); *
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Symbol - * represent that these variables are arraylists. So, I'am getting this error: `No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.ArrayList to a known managed provider native type.`

How to fix, so could add everything to database?

Comment: maybe the easiest way to get result is that put each of your arrayLists into a foreach loop !

Comment: What is the column type of `Countries`?

Comment: Column type in database : nchar(100)

Answer (score 1):

If your database doesn't support array types and you don't want to extract your Contries, Languages etc into separate referenced tables, I guess you are left with flattening your ArrayList to a string like so:

```
    // Convert the ArrayList to a string
    string separator = "|"; // Any string that doesn't collide with content
    string arrayListAsString = String.Join(separator, Contries.ToArray());
```

Then save the string in the database. When reading the string from the database you'll probably want to convert it back to an ArrayList:

```
    // Convert the string back to an ArrayList
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.AddRange(arrayListAsString.Split(new string[]{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: Getting error:`String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated.` At line:`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: This sounds like the string you are saving are longer than what the database column accepts.

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear. I guess you'll have to go through each value you send to the database and check its length against the corresponding database columns length.

Comment: You need to hold it up against the strings you are sending to the database. The column size of 2000 is no guarantee of success if one of your strings are 2001 (or more) characters long. What is the length of your longest string? I guess columns like plot and cast could easily exceed 2000 chars. Set a breakpoint and step through each of your strings runtime and check their length. With an error message like the one you describe, this really got to be a case of content exceeding columns length.